# how do I show all enum values from database in Java

Tags: java, mysql, enums, jcombobox

I have 3 values stored as ENUM in my MySQL database.

What I basically want to do is retrieve all this three items and store them in a JComboBox. with the selected enum item from the database as the selected item in the combobox.

At this moment I retrieve just only the current value as string from database and use this method to put all items  in the combo box.

```
private enum statusTypes {Beschikbaar, verhuurd, onderhoud};
txtstatus = new JComboBox();
txtstatus.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(statusTypes.values()));
```

The way to get the item from the database is like

```
String s = model.getStatus();
```

So how can I tell Java to put the value I get as the first value of my combo box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your `String` to the `Enum`:

```
//consider using Java naming convention
private enum StatusTypes {BESCHIKBAAR, VERHUURD, ONDERHOUD};
...
String s = model.getStatus();
...
StatusTypes status = StatusTypes.valueOf(s);
```

Comment: And how do I put that "database enum value" as the first value in my combo box?

Comment: How about [setSelectedItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object))?

Comment: ah ye sorry :p new with java so don;t know the syntax very good